# SilverStripe: Latest Blog Posts Content Block

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm using SheaDawson's [blocks module](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks), and I'm trying to create a "latest blog posts" content block. Here is my DataObject:

```
<?php

class LatestBlogPosts extends Block {
    private static $db = array(
        'ContainInGrid' => 'Boolean',
        'PostCount' => 'Int'
    );

    static $defaults = array(
        "PostCount" => 2
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        return $fields;
    }

    public function LatestPosts() {
        $blog = DataObject::get("BlogEntry", "", "Date DESC", "", $this->PostCount);
        return $blog;
    }
}
```

On the page template it's not displaying any posts. It says it can't find any. When I checked the database the `BlogEntry` table is empty, even though I have two posts that are published.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest version of the [SilverStripe blog module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/) the blog entry class is named [`BlogPost`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/blob/master/code/model/BlogPost.php). `BlogEntry` is what the class used to be, but this changed sometime in 2015.

If you are using the latest version of the blog module your blog entries will be created as `BlogPost`s and that data will be in the `BlogPost` database table.

Your `LatestPosts` function should look like this:

```
public function LatestPosts() {
    return BlogPost::get()->sort('Date', 'DESC')->limit($this->PostCount);
}
```